# How to replace the Unicode gem on Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, unicode, rubygems, ruby-1.9

Unfortunately, the Unicode 0.1 (`sudo gem install unicode`) doesn't work on Ruby 1.9. I have the following snippet:

```
require "rubygems"
require "unicode"

str = "áéíóúç"
Unicode.normalize_KD(str).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n, "")
#=> aeiouc
```

I use it to convert titles to permalink, without removing accented characters.

Is there a way of converting such texts using `pack` or `unpack` methods?

Comment: You should dig through the ruby-talk archives. I am pretty sure that within the last few days/weeks, the author of the Unicode gem announced a new version there, and I'm also pretty sure that Ruby 1.9 was discussed in that thread. I didn't actually read the thread, though, so I don't have any specifics.

Comment: Actually, that was *not* the Unicode gem, but the Unicode-Utils gem mentioned by @molf below. (It also wasn't in the past few days, it was 3 months ago.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** a better option may be to use the gem [`unicode_utils`](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) that was created specifically for these missing features:

```
require "unicode_utils"
UnicodeUtils.nfkd("áéíóúç").gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,'').to_s
#=> "aeiouc"
```

---

Is there a possibility you can depend on Rails' ActiveSupport? Then you can do the following:

```
require "activesupport"
mb_str = ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars.new("áéíóúç")
mb_str.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,'').to_s
#=> "aeiouc"
```

`ActiveSupport::Multibyte` was written to bring UTF-8/Unicode support to Ruby 1.8, but works fine in 1.9 too. You may be able to borrow some of [the code](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e93d0a50c0e8cdc2507a7a211fc96404ad738152/activesupport/lib/active_support/multibyte/chars.rb) if you don't want it as an external dependency.

Comment: Nice replacement! I use Unicode gem on a Rails plugin, so sure I can rely on it! Thanks a lot! Would be nice to have a replacement using Ruby 1.9 only though, because there are a lot of gems that use it and ActiveSupport may not be a choice for all of them.

Comment: That's the one I was thinking about in my comment above. Thanks for reminding me about that! I'm actually going to need that right now in my toy project.

Comment: I think is better to use the unicode-utils gem instead of ActiveSupport when replacing unicode on gems! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is also `I18n.transliterate('string')` method in Rails. Works like a charm.

Comment: I can't find references for this method, can you provide a link to the documentation? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, looks like `#to_latin` has been removed.