# Ruby - internationalized domain names

Tags: ruby

I need to support internationalized domain names in an app I am writing. More specifically, I need to ACE encode domain names before I pass them on to an external API.

The best way to do this seems to be by using [libidn](http://idn.rubyforge.org/docs/). However, I have problems installing it on my development machine (Windows 7, ruby 1.8.6), as it complains about not finding the GNU IDN library (which I have installed, and also provided the full path to).

So basically I am considering two things:

1. Search the web for a prebuilt win32 libidn gem (fruitless so far)
2. Find another (hopefully pure) ruby library that can do the same thing (not found apperantly as I am asking this question here)

So have anyone of you got libidn to work under Windows? Or have you used some other library/code snippet that is able to encode domain names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4575), I finally found a solution that did not require libidn. It is built upon [punicode4r](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/punycode4r/) together with either the [unicode](http://ruby-unicode.rubyforge.org/doc/) gem (a prebuilt binary can be found [here](http://supremetyrant.com/ruby/unicode-0.1-mswin32.gem)), or with ActiveSupport. I will use ActiveSupport since I use Rails anyway, but for reference I include both methods.

With the **unicode** gem:

```
require 'unicode'
require 'punycode' #This is not a gem, but a standalone file.

   def idn_encode(domain)
    parts = domain.split(".").map do |label|
        encoded = Punycode.encode(Unicode::normalize_KC(Unicode::downcase(label)))
        if encoded =~ /-$/ #Pure ASCII
            encoded.chop!
        else #Contains non-ASCII characters
            "xn--" + encoded
        end
    end
    parts.join(".")
end
```

With **ActiveSupport**:

```
require "punycode"
require "active_support"
$KCODE = "UTF-8" #Have to set this to enable mb_chars

def idn_encode(domain)
    parts = domain.split(".").map do |label|
        encoded = Punycode.encode(label.mb_chars.downcase.normalize(:kc))
        if encoded =~ /-$/ #Pure ASCII
            encoded.chop! #Remove trailing '-'
        else #Contains non-ASCII characters
            "xn--" + encoded
        end
    end
    parts.join(".")
end
```

The ActiveSupport solution was found thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322856/how-to-replace-the-unicode-gem-on-ruby-1-9) StackOverflow question.

Comment: For what it's worth, the punycode module is available as a gem, in a gemfile:

     `gem 'punycode4r', require: 'punycode' # internationalization of domain names`