# How to convert UTF8 combined Characters into single UTF8 characters in ruby?

Tags: ruby, utf-8

Some characters such as the Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON' can be encoded as `0xC4 0x8D`, but can also be represented with the two code points for 'LATIN SMALL LETTER C' and 'COMBINING CARON', which is `0x63 0xcc 0x8c`.
More info here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d/index.htm

I wonder if there is a library which can convert a 'LATIN SMALL LETTER C' + 'COMBINING CARON' into 'LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON'. Or is there a table containing these conversions?

Comment: Please do not be thinking about 8-bit code units.  Think only of logical code points.  You can use `unicode_utils` for converting into NFC form, but that does not do what you want, because what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you use Unicode Normalization to do this.

Using UnicodeUtils.nfkc using the gem unicode_utils (https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) should get you the specific behavior you're asking for; unicode normalization form kC will use a compatibility decomposition followed by converting the string to a composed form, if available (basically what you asked for by your example). (You may also get close to what you want with normalization form c, sometimes acronymized NFC).

[How to replace the Unicode gem on Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322856/how-to-replace-the-unicode-gem-on-ruby-1-9) has additional details.

In Ruby 1.8.7, you'd need do gem install Unicode, for which there is a similar function available.

Edited to add: The main reason why you'll probably want normalization form kC instead of just normalization form C is that ligatures (characters that are squeezed together for historical/typographical reasons) will first be decomposed to the individual characters, which is sometimes desirable if you're doing lexicographic ordering or searching).

Comment: You assume that such a precombined character exists. That is not a good assumption. Notice how U+0035 ‹5› `DIGIT FIVE` followed by U+0304 ‹◌̄› `COMBINING MACRON` has no shorter rendering in NFC than it has in NFD. Only a few legacy code points have precombined characters.  Most do not.

Comment: No, I said "if available." Made no such assumption.

Answer (score 8):

These conversions don't always exist. The combination of U+0063 (c) with U+030C (combining caron) can be represented as a single character, for instance, but there's no precomposed character representing a lowercase 'w' with a caron (w̌).

Nevertheless, there exist libraries which can perform this composition where possible. Look for a Unicode function called "NFC" (Normalization Form: Composition). See, for instance: http://unicode-utils.rubyforge.org/classes/UnicodeUtils.html#M000015

Answer (score 0):

String#encode can be used since Ruby 1.9. UTF-8-MAC is a variant of NFD. The codepoints in the range between U+2000 and U+2FFF, or U+F900 and U+FAFF, or U+2F800 and U+2FAFF are not decomposed. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1173/_index.html for the details. UTF-8-HFS can be also used insted of UTF-8-MAC.

```
# coding: utf-8

s = "\u010D"
s.encode!('UTF-8-MAC', 'UTF-8')
s.force_encoding('UTF-8')

p "\x63\xcc\x8c" == s
p "\u0063" == s[0]
p "\u030C" == s[1]
```